# How to convert update query in django

Tags: mysql, django

I want to use the query below in **django**.

```
update notes from Testcase where (testid==givenid);
```

I tried this but it's not working unfortunately. How can I write this in django ?

```
Testcase.objects.filter(id=givenid).upadte(notes)
```

Comment: It's written in the manual, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once
Try it in a shell first if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tc = Testcase.objects.get(id=givenid)
tc.some_field = "some_value"
tc.save()
```